# Is there any problem to have many ReactDOM.render() in a ReactJS Project?

Tags: reactjs

We are working on a Laravel project and it is written totally with JavaScript/HTML/JQuery. We are considering migrating to React as Laravel supports it. Is it OK to have many ReactDOM.render() ( per component) in the initial steps  so we can progressively and fully convert our code base in the long run?

Is it necessary to access `ref` or just we can render each component like this:

```
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#form"))
```

and use it like this for every component:

```
// some html code and then
...
<div id="form"> </div>
<div id="modal"> </div>
<div id="navbar"> </div>
...


// rest of html code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is totally fine, when you call `ReactDOM.render` multiple times it will basically just triggers a diffing, very similar to the `render` method of a class component.
I actually wrote an article (with a tutorial) about ["Integrate React with other applications and frameworks"](https://blog.usejournal.com/integrate-react-with-other-applications-and-frameworks-94d443e3cc3f) that talks exactly about that topic.

The bottom line of this approach is that you can expose a global object with `mount` and `unmount` functions of your widget / mini-app and inside it call `ReactDOM.render` or `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode`.

```
window.MyComponent = {
    mount: (props, container) => {
        ReactDOM.render(<Component {...props} />, container);
    },
    unmount: (container) => {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    }
}
```

Then in another part in the page you can call these functions, no matter what library or framework you are using obviously.

The beauty here, is that other `react` applications can use it as if it was a real component:

```
class MyComponentWrapper extends PureComponent {

    // create a ref so we can pass the element to mount and unmount
    myRef = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        // initial render with props
        window.MyComponent.mount(this.props, this.myRef.current);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps !== this.props){
            window.MyComponent.mount(this.props, this.myRef.current);
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        window.MyComponent.unmount(this.myRef.current);
    }

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.myRef}></div>
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I just elaborated more on my comment so I'm making myself crystal clear

Comment: @RaminJafary ok, is this fit your needs?

Comment: The way you explained is fantastic. The project is huge and hooking React into the project I assume we may not have the advantage of having one root element and then render other component in the same root DOM tree (as I understood in your article, I think!).So is it ok to have many separate containers for every component until the project is converted to fully SPA. Is there any performance hit for such workflow?

Comment: This is exactly my point. You can wrap each section in its own app (root)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's completely fine. React is designed for gradual adoption.